# Type 1 Chebyshev 3rd Order Lowpass Filter

Tags: filter-design, lowpass-filter, c++, chebyshev-filters

I'm trying to implement a 3rd order Type 1 Chebyshev digital lowpass filter in C++. I've been having a lot of problems and I'm not sure why. I can plot the transfer function in MATLAB and see that it works, but when I do the bilinear transform manually the frequency response isn't as expected.

$\epsilon=\sqrt{10^{r_\mathrm{dB}/10}-1}) \qquad \qquad r_\mathrm{dB} = \text{passband gain ripple in dB}$

$g=\frac{10^{r_{dB}/20}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2}}}$

$v = \frac{1}{n}\sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$

$\alpha_i = -\sin(\frac{\pi(2k-1))}{2n})\cdot\sinh(v)$

$\beta_i= \cos(\frac{\pi(2k-1))}{2n})\cdot\cosh(v)$

$p_i=\alpha_i+j\beta_i$

General $n$th-order Chebyshev transfer function
$H(s) = g\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{s-p_i}$

So for a 3rd-order Chebyshev type 1 LPF transfer function I have:

$H(s) = \frac{g}{(s-p_1)(s-p_2)(s-p_3)}$

$H(s) = \frac{g}{s^3-p_2s^2-p_1s^2+p_1p_2s-p_3s^2+p_2p_3s+p_1p_3s-p_1p_2p_3}$

$s \gets \frac{s}{\omega_c}$

$H(s) = \frac{g}{\frac{s}{\omega_c}^3-p_2\frac{s}{\omega_c}^2-p_1\frac{s}{\omega_c}^2+p_1p_2\frac{s}{\omega_c}-p_3\frac{s}{\omega_c}^2+p_2p_3\frac{s}{\omega_c}+p_1p_3\frac{s}{\omega_c}-p_1p_2p_3}$

$= \frac{\omega_c^3}{\omega_c^3} \cdot \frac{g}{\frac{s}{\omega_c}^3-p_2\frac{s}{\omega_c}^2-p_1\frac{s}{\omega_c}^2+p_1p_2\frac{s}{\omega_c}-p_3\frac{s}{\omega_c}^2+p_2p_3\frac{s}{\omega_c}+p_1p_3\frac{s}{\omega_c}-p_1p_2p_3}$

$= \frac{g}{s^3-p_2s^2\omega_c-p_1s^2\omega_c+p_1p_2s^2\omega_c-p_3s^2\omega_c+p_2p_3s\omega_c^2+p_1p_3s\omega_c^2-p_1p_2p_3\omega_c^3}$

Then from here I just do the bilinear transform to obtain my difference equation for the filter and I'd expect that I can just re calculate the poles based off of whatever dB I'd like the ripple to be. With a cutoff frequency

$\omega_c = \tan(\frac{\pi f_c}{f_s})$

However, this seems to only work correctly for high frequency values, and I'm not getting the results I would expect.

*Edit:*
I went ahead and worked this out further.

$= \frac{g}{s^3-s^2\omega_c(p_1+p_2+p_3)+s\omega_c^2(p_1p_2+p_1p_3+p_2p_3)-p_1p_2p_3\omega_c^3}$

$a = p_1+p_2+p_3$

$b = p_1p_2+p_1p_3+p_2p_3$

$c = p_1p_2p_3$

$= \frac{g}{s^3-s^2a\omega_c+sb\omega_c^2-c\omega_c^3}$

Then once I do the bilinear transform I get the coefficients:

$b_0 = \omega_c^3$

$b_1 = 3\omega_c^3$

$b_2 = 3\omega_c^3$

$b_3 = \omega_c^3$

$a_0 = 1 + a\omega_c + b\omega_c^2 + c\omega_c^3$

$a_1 = -3 - a\omega_c + b\omega_c^2 + 3c\omega_c^3$

$a_2 = 3 - a\omega_c - b\omega_c^2 + 3c\omega_c^3$

$a_3 = -1 + a\omega_c - b\omega_c^2 + c\omega_c^3$

Applied to the difference equation:

$y(n) = \frac{g}{a_0}[b_0x(n)+b_1x(n-1)+b_2x(n-2)+b_3x(n-3)-a_1y(n-1)-a_2y(n-2)-a_3y(n-3)]$

When I actually apply this in a C++ program the frequency response is not as I'd expect.

[image: Chebyshev Filter Implementation at 4000Hz]

So for the cutoff frequency of 4000Hz and a $r_{dB} = 0.707$ I find in my program that:

$H_0 = 0.849180579$

$w_c = 0.267949194$

$a = 1.04937625$

$b = 0.344122052$

$c = -0.0361113548$

Then calculating the coefficients:

$b_0 = 0.0192378871$

$b_1 = 0.0577136613$

$b_2 = b_1$

$b_3 = b_0$

$a_0 = 1.30519164$

$a_1 = -3.25855660$

$a_2 = 2.69202971$

$a_3 = -0.744282126$

As I increase the $r_{dB}$ *or* the cutoff frequency the resonance gets narrower and the passband gets quieter.

Comment: Do you know the difference between "$w$" and "$\omega$"?

Comment: I'm still learning for sure, but I believe that $\omega$ is the angular frequency. This is what I was intending to use, and hopefully should all be corrected. I see I missed that again when I made edits.

Comment: Are you sure you got $$a = p_1-p_2-p_3$$ right?  Why should $p_1$ have a different $\pm$ sign?

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, it was meant to be $a = p_1 + p_2 + p_3$, where I factored out the $-s^2$

Comment: Where did you get this equation from?

$$y(n) = \frac{g}{a_0}\frac{b_0x(n)+b_1x(n-1)+b_2x(n-2)+b_3x(n-3)}{a_1y(n-1)-a_2y(n-2)-a_3y(n-3)}$$

Comment: Another typo..  I did not implement it this way. I actually used your Audio EQ Cookbook for reference and a starting point for a lot of what I've been learning so far! What I actually am doing is 
<br/>
$y(n) = \frac{1}{A0}\cdot [b_0x(n)+b_1x(n-1)+b_2x(n-2)+b_3x(n-3)-a_1y(n-1)-a_2y(n-2)-a_3y(n-3)]\\$ 
<br/>
and g is the gain factor to get the magnitude of the passband to the desired level 
<br/>
$g=\frac{10^{r_{dB}/20}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2}}}$.

Comment: When you say "applied to the difference equation $y(n) = \frac{g}{A0}\frac{b_0x(n)+b_1x(n-1)+b_2x(n-2)+b_3x(n-3)}{a_1y(n-1)-a_2y(n-2)-a_3y(n-3)}$" -- is that really what you mean?  The Chebychev filter is linear, so the difference equation is (or can be put into) the form $y(n) = \sum_{k=0}^K b_n x(n-k) - \sum_{k=1}^K a_n x(n - k)$.  If the answer is "no I did not mean that" then please _edit your question_.

Comment: It would also be good if you would _show us actual numbers_ for an example that works and an example that does not -- there are problems that can crop up when a filter's poles get close to the unit circle (i.e., when the cutoff frequency of a high- or lowpass filter, as a fraction of the sampling rate, is close to zero).

Comment: Yeah you're right, I should have edited the post before I see that now. I updated it as well as adding a specific example with calculated variables (The image reflects the example too). It seems to become unstable pretty easily as well, at below 2500Hz and above 13000Hz where the outputs become -nan(ind). I need to probably debug it a bit more I think I may need to switch these filters to double precision as well as I was reading that these filters can become pretty unstable in single precision.

Comment: Your difference equation gives $b_0$ through $b_3$, $a_1$ through $a_3$, $g$, and $A0$.  You list coefficients with $a_0$ through $a_3$, but do not give $g$ or $A0$.  Please _give us enough information to help you_.  Don't assume that because you have it in a book there's a consistent way to go from one form to another -- every author (even me) invents their favorite way and pushes that as the only way.

Comment: Yeah, understandable! In hindsight I may have been a little excited to post about this stuff and didn't review it enough. In the future I will try to make it more consistent before I ask a question. I updated the post to include both g and fixed it so that the difference equation properly shows $a_0$. For clarification I found the formula for $g$ in a separate text and I can't find it right now, but my understanding was that it was supposed to help bring the levels of the filter back to unity.